# Lubuntu and steamcmd

Tags: lubuntu

I am trying to install `steamcmd` on Lubuntu. I've been following this guide
http://korbinbrown.com/how-to-host-a-left-4-dead-2-server-on-linux-ubuntu/
and every time I start `steamcmd`, I get this:

```
./steamcmd.sh: line 29: /home/matexoza/l4d2/linux32/steamcmd: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure how to get this to work.